# String cannot be cast to JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have a problem with JSON, which gives me a casting error on a string. I had already used this code in the past and no error, and I reuse it and boom x)

Here is the line with error:

```
JSONArray groups = (JSONArray) data.get("groups");
```

I show you the whole code (the first 3 variables come from a database):

```
String name = set.getString("name");
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(set.getString("uuid"));
String json = set.getString("data");

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(json);
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) obj;

String prefix = (String) data.get("prefix");
String suffix = (String) data.get("suffix");
boolean superUser = (boolean) data.get("super");

JSONArray privileges = (JSONArray) data.get("privileges");
JSONArray groups = (JSONArray) data.get("groups");
```

PS: I have already searched the internet for the same problem but it is frequently with JSONObject and not JSONArray.

Comment: It would help if you'd share the relevant portions of the json as well. My guess would be that `"groups"` isn't an array but a single value.

Comment: have you checked what data.get("groups"); returns?

Comment: @Stultuske data.get("groups") return a String, but if there are multiple groups, it should return a string as well ? data in sql: '{"super":false,"privileges":[],"groups":"Group1","suffix":null,"prefix":null}' .

Comment: yes, but "hello", is also a String. Yet it is one that can not be cast into a JSon array.

Comment: @Stultuske what is the solution ? Want me to show you the output of data.get("groups")?

Comment: the solution is assuming that not all your responses can be cast to a json array. Either test beforehand whether the syntax is valid for a json array, or add a try-catch block around it. or, change it so that you'll always have a valid json array returned

Comment: Based on the example in the comments above, the `data.groups` key maps to a String - the example showing `{..,"groups":"Group1",..}`.  It is _NOT_ an array so you cannot cast it into one. If the data is supposed to be an array then the form for a single entry should be  `["Group1"]`.  The String may be a comma-separated list of values but it is just a String in JSON.

Consider adding the sample JSON to the question.